# In C99, can I use a return value without first assigning it to a variable?

Tags: c, macros, inline, c99

I am replacing macros in a large C99 code base with inline functions to see if the compiler can do a better job optimizing.  There are a lot of macros which expand to a data structure.  The code uses them not as functions, but as a replacement for the data structure itself.

For example...

```
#define AvARRAY(av)     ((av)->sv_u.svu_array)

AvARRAY(av)[--key] = &PL_sv_undef;
```

Not only is there a lot of code which does this, published code outside of my control does this, so I would rather leave this idiom in place if possible.

Is there a way to define an inline function version of `AvARRAY` which is compatible with the sort of code above?

Comment: You say the goal is optimization, are you thinking there are some magic instructions that an inline function might be able to use that would be faster than a pointer-offset? Have you manually unrolled the macro expansion and thought about what function might be more efficient?

Comment: @kfsone I've learned that compilers are often smarter than I am these days, and I figure more structure and type checks will give it more to work with.  I've also learned that when I try to guess what the compiler will do I'm often wrong.  I'd like to see what happens.  Finally, the extensive use of macros in this source makes understanding what's going on and debugging a bit of a nightmare.

Comment: There is no reason at all that in the example you are giving, an `inline` function would be better optimized or saver then the macro. You are evaluating the argument only once, and from the use, the thing is quite type safe, since you are using the `->` operator on the argument. It looks you are hunting a phantom. (To have better compiler support with macro I'd recommend to use clang) I see one nasty thing in your code, though, that is gratuitous use of `--` inside another expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use the return value without assigning it to a variable.

However, in general case it is not possible to replace this macro with a function. The whole point of using macros in for this purpose is that macros can "evaluate" to lvalues. Functions in C cannot produce lvalues, unfortunately. In other words, no, in general case you can't directly replace such macros with a functions.

But in specific case it could be different. Do they really use those macros as lvalues? In your specific example it is not used as an lvalue, so in your case you can just do

```
inline whatever_type_it_has *AvARRAY(struct_type *av)
{
  return av->sv_u.svu_array;
}
```

and use it later exactly as it is used in your example

```
AvARRAY(av)[--key] = &PL_sv_undef;
```

But if somewhere else in the code you have something like

```
AvARRAY(av) = malloc(some_size);
```

or

```
whatever_type_it_has **pptr = &AvARRAY(av);
```

then you'll be out of luck. The function version will not work, while the original macro will.

The only way to [almost] fully "emulate" the functionality of macro with a function in this case is to lift it to a higher level of indirection, i.e. assume that the function always returns *a pointer* to the target data field

```
inline whatever_type_it_has **AvARRAY_P(struct_type *av)
{
  return &av->sv_u.svu_array;
}
```

In that case you will have to remember to dereference that pointer every time

```
(*(AvARRAY_P(av))[--key] = &PL_sv_undef;
```

but this will work

```
*AvARRAY_P(av) = malloc(some_size);
whatever_type_it_has **pptr = &*AvARRAY_P(av);
```

But this will not work with bit-fields, while the macro version will.

Comment: It is used as an lvalue, but far more often it's used in the way described to set a specific slot in the array.  I've defined another function to replace its use as an lvalue.